# Delete second level of belonging in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My application has a `Category` model. Each `Category` can have many `Subcategories`, so each `Subcategory` `belongsTo` a `Category`. From the `Subcategory` model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

On the other hand, there's a `Friend` model. Now, each `Friend/Subcategory` pair is connected through the pivot `friend_score` table:

```
id | friend_id | subcategory_id | score
```

From the `Subcategory` model:

```
/**
 * The friend scores that belong to the subcategory.
 */
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend', 'friend_score')->withPivot('score');
}
```

From the `Friend` model:

```
/**
 * The subcategory scores that belong to the friend.
 */
public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subcategory', 'friend_score')->withPivot('score');
}
```

When I delete a subcategory, Eloquent automatically, and correctly, deletes the entries from the friend_score table for that `subcategory_id`.

When I delete a category, it correctly deletes the subcategories that belong to that `category_id`. However, in this case, the related friend_scores remain in the database.

How do I make it delete the friend_score for each child subcategory when deleting a category?

I'm aware I could manually iterate through them and delete them, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make this happen automatically through model relationships.

Comment: can you show subcategory table structure ?

Comment: @TeomanTıngır It's just `id | category_id | name | created_at | updated_at`

Answer (score 0):

In your `friend_score` migration, You can define subcategory_id as foreign key. Then you can choose what will happen to pivot records with `onDelete()` method when sub category deleted.

```
$table->foreign('subcategory_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('subcategories')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

With cascade option, when sub category deleted, all related pivot records will removed..

So when you deleted a category, deleting will bubble to friend scores through sub category

category-> subcategory -> friend scores (pivot)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to accomplish the same from inside the model, rather than through the migration?

Comment: @jovan Well, you can delete manually but it requires extra queries. Why you don't let the database to handle with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the migration and add `onDelete()` cascading, which will be my preferred way of handling such cases. But if you are really looking to do this manually, you can use eloquent's events like follows :

`Subcategory` Model :

```
/**
 * Boot eloquent model events
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    // This will be called just before deleting a
    // subcategory entry

    static::deleting(function($subcategory) {

        Friend::where('subcategory_id', $subcategory->id)->delete();
    });
}
```

Before doing any of it, you can do a cleanup by following :

```
Friend::whereDoesntHave('subcategories')->get();
```

Check if above returns correct result of entries which does not have any relation of subcategories table. Then you can call `->delete()` instead of `->get()` to clean up the friend model entries.